# How can I describe the intersection between a circle and a curve?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-curves, curves

I have a curve C and a point x in the curve. At the point x, I draw a circle B with radius r and centered at point x. That circle B will segment/intersect (with) the curve C as red sub-curve line. I would like to use English to describe the sub-curve. Could you see my describe and give me some correct and professional way for it? Thank in advance

This is my example image:

[image]

> The sub-curve at point x, which intersects between the curve C and the circle B, is red color

Or

> The arc of the point x which is segmented by the curve C and circle B, is red color

Which one is better to define the sub-curve? If it is possible, let suggest to me the other way

Comment: I'm confused, the red curve is supposed to be contained in $C$?  Because it doesn't look like it is from your picture.  But if that's what you mean then perhaps you can just say the part of the curve $C$ that is inside the circle $B$

Comment: The red curve is a part of curve $C$. Sorry I use visio to draw it so it is not so correct,

Comment: $\{y\in C \mid d(x,y)\leq r\}$.

Comment: Sorry. I am Iooking for a sentence to describe the red sub-curve

Comment: I gave it to you already, it's "the part of the curve $C$ that is inside the circle $B$"

Comment: I see. I was misunderstand your ans.

Answer (score 0):

Red Curve is the intersection of disk, with center at $x$ with radius $r$, and curve C.

i-e $\text{Red curve} = (x-x_1)^2 + (y-y_1)^2 \le r^2 \cap C$.

where $ x =(x_1,x_2).$

So, instead of defining a circle define it as a 2-D region(disk).

Comment: For your definition. If I want to said about area inside and outside of circle B which segmented by the red curve, can I said as "the area inside and outside the disk which segmented by the red curve" or something is better?